# Prove that a polynomial function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've only seen examples of proving linear transformation of matrices from our module but none of this kind so i'm lost.

Say given the function:
$$ L: R_{2}[t] \rightarrow R_{1}[t]$$
$$ at^{2} + bt + c \rightarrow at + 2c - b $$

We are asked to prove that L is a linear transformation but I don't really know where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a transformation $T:V \to V$ on a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is linear, what you do is take $\alpha v + \beta w$, where $\alpha,\beta \in F$ and $v,w \in V$ (and thus $\alpha v + \beta w \in V$), and show that

$$T(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha T(v) + \beta T(w)$$

Thus, in your case, take two polynomials, $p_i(t) = a_i t^2 + b_i t + c_i \in \Bbb R_2[t]$ for $i = 1,2$. Then, for scalars $\alpha_i \in \Bbb R$, $i=1,2$, show that

$$L(\alpha_1 p_1(t) + \alpha_2 p_2(t) ) = \alpha_1 T(p_1(t)) + \alpha_2 T(p_2(t))$$

Comment: What does 'take two polynomials'  mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special. I'm just saying to define two polynomials, $p_i(t)$, and show that identity on the last line of the post

Comment: What would these polynomials look like?

Comment: Quadratics, as defined in your vector space $\Bbb R_2[t]$. I defined them by

$$p_i(t) = a_i t^2 + b_i t + c_i$$

where $i=1,2$, so we can have two polynomials.

Comment: I see thanks! I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Take two polynomials $at^2+bt+c$ and $a't^2+b't+c'$ and take the image by $L$. You get:

\begin{align*}
L((at^2+bt+c)+(a't^2+b't+c'))
&=L((a+a')t^2+(b+b')t+(c+c'))\\
&=(a+a')t+2(c+c')-(b+b')\\
&=(at+2ct-b)+(a't+2c'-b')
\end{align*}

This is $L$ of the first polynomial + $L$ of the second polynomial. Same when multiplying a polynomial by a constant $\alpha$.

Comment: What is a′t2+b′t+c′?

Comment: It is another polynomial of degree 2.